Sitecore cannot access the initialised gitsubmodule folder
I am using bitbucket pipleines to deploy to sitecore. In the pipline we are initialising the gitsubmodule before running the sitecore deploy command.Below is the pipeline code
deployToSitecore: &deployToSitecore
step:
    name: Build and Deploy to Sitecore
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    caches:
        - dotnetcore
    script:
        - bash ./ci-scripts/npmrc.sh
        - bash ./updateSubmodules.sh
        ## Install Sitecore CLI
        - dotnet tool install Sitecore.CLI --version 5.2.113
        ## Log in to XM Cloud
        - dotnet sitecore cloud login --client-credentials --client-id $ClientID --client-secret $ClientSecret
        ## Deploy to environment
        - dotnet sitecore cloud deployment create --environment-id $EnvironmentID --upload --verbose

code in updateSubmodules.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Update linux package lists (required for next command)
apt-get update
# Install an SSH Client so we can connect to submodule repositories using SSH
apt-get -y install openssh-client
# Update the .gitmodules file replacing HTTPS references with SSH references
sed -i 's!https://bitbucket.org/test/mtv!git@bitbucket.org:mptv!g' .gitmodules
# Clone submodule repositories
git submodule update --init
# Change permissions of the submodule directory to be accessible by anyone
chmod -R 777 src/sxastarter/ptv-components
ls -ld src/sxastarter/ptv-components

Even though the gitsubmodule is cloned properly, cloned folder is not recognised by the Sitecore deployment command. You can see I have set the permission properly to that folder in updatesubmodule.sh .

I  checked whether the cloned folder is available in the pipeline by adding it as an artifact and it was there. Somehow its not passed to the Sitecore deployment command.

the deployment --upload command will upload all files in the working folder, while obeying the .gitignore rules. Check your .gitignore file and make sure that submodule folder is not in there.
